# How to get the element with the max number of children with xpath

Tags: xpath

I have xml like that

```
<ns1:row>
<ns2:day>
<ns2:class>Math</ns2:class>
<ns2:class>English</ns2:class>
<ns2:class>Physics</ns2:class>
</ns2:day>
<ns2:day>
<ns2:class>Math</ns2:class>
</ns2:day>
<ns2:day/>
</ns1:row>
```

what I want to have, is the max number of classes in a day in a row
so for this example my result should be `3`

I tried this `xpath` :

```
max(//*[local-name()='row']/*[local-name()='day']/count(/*[local-name()='class']))
```

but the result is `0`!
any help please ?